# where to put transition - dropdown menu animation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-animations, css-transitions

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">ALAT</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="index2.php"><img src="home.jpg" class="home" width="70px" height="50px" title="Dashboard"></a>
    <a href="papar_topik.php"><img src="quiz.jpg" class="quiz" width="70px" height="50px" title="Kuiz"></a> 
    <a href="prestasi_topik.php"><img src="prestasi.png" width="70px" height="50px" title="Prestasi Pelajar"></a> 
    <a href="senarai_pelajar.php"><img src="senarai.jpg" class="senarai" width="70px" height="50px" title="Senarai Pelajar"></a> 
    <a href="import_daftar.php"><img src="import.jpg" class="import" width="70px" height="50px" title="Import Daftar"></a> 
    <a href="#" onclick="logout()"><img src="logout.png" width="70px" height="50px" title="Keluar"></a>
```

The above is my code to make a dropdown button. I want to make the dropdown content to be appearead in transition when the mouse moves near the button. Below is my CSS code:

```
div{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        top: 170px;
        left: 1000px;
    }
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: aqua;
        color: black;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: brush script mt;
        font-style: bold;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: cornsilk;
        width: 120px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        height: 0px;
        transition: all .5s ease;
    
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        top: 10px;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

However, the dropdown content did not show any transition but just appear as usual. Anyone can direct me on where should I put the "transition" tag?

Comment: You can not animate ```display```, try animating ```height``` in combination with ```overflow```.

Answer (score 1):

When we want to use transition for display:none to display:block, transition properties do not work. The reason for this is, display:none property is used for removing block and display:block property is used for displaying block. A block cannot be partly displayed. Either it is available or unavailable. That is why the transition property does not work.
[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-transition-properties-does-not-work-with-display-properties/)

> Anyone can direct me on where should I put the "transition" tag?
> You are using transition property for correct selector but instead using diplay property you should use opacity.
> Here you can see changes that I made on your CSS.

```
    div{
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        top: 170px;
        left: 1000px;
    }
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: aqua;
        color: black;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: brush script mt;
        font-style: bold;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: fixed;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
        opacity: 0;   // instead display:none use opactiy:0
        position: fixed;
        background-color: cornsilk;
        width: 120px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        height: 0px;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        opacity: 1;   // instead display:block use opactiy:1
        top: 10px;
        height: 1000px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead of your code

```
div{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 170px;
    left: 1000px;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: brush script mt;
    font-style: bold;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: cornsilk;
    width: 120px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all .5s ease;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 100;
    top: 10px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you everyone!problem solved